# Azure datafactory v2 -dataset copy activty -zipdeflate

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to deploy Azure dataset using PowerShell. While doing this activity, I was uploading json file to ADF.

**Issue**:
I am uploading json file with below format.

> "compression": {
>                   "type": "ZipDeflate",
>                   "level": "Optimal"
>               }

but when I m checking at Azure environment ,it is changed like below ,

> "compression": {
>                   "type": "Datasetcompression"                }

Kindly help me in resolving this issue ...

Thanks in advance .